# What is meaning of "Wrestling words into submission"?

Tags: meaning, american-english, punctuation, british-english, subcontinental-english

I came across a sentence which goes "**I knew I wasn't meant to spend my life locked away in a silent room alone and half-crazed, wrestling words into submission**."

Can some please tell me what it means?

Comment: What is the larger context of this sentence? for example, is the person a writer?

Comment: @katatahito yes! he is a writer..

Comment: It's a metaphor. Do you understand what *wrestling* is? If not, there are many online dictionaries to assist. If yes, can you see how words are being conceptualised as opponents that need to be conquered? English is full of metaphors. If this doesn't make sense, you might find our other site [ell.se] more useful for your level of fluency. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This phrase is using "wrestling" in a metaphorical sense. This sense of wrestling is a pretty common usage of the word.

See this [source](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wrestling) with definitions I have copied below.

> 1. Literally, to grapple with someone or an animal in an attempt to subdue and immobilize or just as part of aggressive play.
>
> > *The kids have been out there wrestling with each other all day.*
> >
> > *The animal control worker had to wrestle with the rabid raccoon to get it in the cage.*
>
> 2. To attempt to handle or move something, typically a large, heavy, or unwieldy object, with much difficulty.
>
> > *We had to wrestle with it a bit, but we got that big bed frame upstairs.*
>
> 3. To attempt to deal with something difficult or troubling, such as a problem or decision.
>
> > *I've wrestled with this equation for hours, but I just can't seem to get it right.*
> >
> > *He's clearly wrestling with his past and trying to make amends for the things he's done.*

The usage in your sentence is closest to the first example sentence under definition #3.

The person is dealing with the difficult task of trying to find the correct words or phrasing to get his meaning across on paper.